# Wrapping default REST error response in custom object

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, exception

I'm building a simple REST api for integration purposes, and i want the response to be as consistent as possible (the same regardless of errors).

I've used the `@ExceptionHandler` method in the past - so I'll most likely go with the class version of this...`@ControllerAdvice` if i remember correctly.

I know it works, I've used SO before to help me, it just requires setting up. **This is not my question...**

The API allows creating messages and searching messages (two separate requests), and thus, accepts date values which are internally validated. Upon testing this i received a really nicely formatted and incredibly detailed error response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-31T10:35:10.748+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "typeMismatch.IntegrationMessageFilter.fromDate",
                "typeMismatch.fromDate",
                "typeMismatch.java.util.Date",
                "typeMismatch"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "IntegrationMessageFilter.fromDate",
                        "fromDate"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "fromDate",
                    "code": "fromDate"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'fromDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat java.util.Date] for value '213-456-45'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
            "objectName": "IntegrationMessageFilter",
            "field": "fromDate",
            "rejectedValue": "213-456-45",
            "bindingFailure": true,
            "code": "typeMismatch"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='IntegrationMessageFilter'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/Integration/get"
}
```

**What i want to do is intercept this error and wrap it in my own response object which will be the same response object for every API method available**:
e.g.

```
{
    "success": Boolean,
    "messageId": Integer, (null on search, int on successful create)
    "messages": Array, (searched IntegrationMessage objects)
    "errorMessage": String, (error message during manual validation (e.g. range validation depending on the field))
    "error" [SPRING DEFAULT ERROR] (this is what i want to intercept from spring-boot and include in this response object)
}
```

It just sees a bit pointless to manually faff about creating a detailed error message when the system does it already...I don't know what object it uses to create the first JSON message above, or even if i can intercept it.

**NOTE:** This is purely for the convenience of the API users not having to differentiate between different response objects, and the convenience for me, not having to re-develop the wheel (so to speak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I've found how to acheive (sort of) what i want.

I was under the impression i could intercept the full exception response message and just put it inside my object, regardless of the type of exception. Turns out, i can get *most* of the default information, but it is specific to each error type (obviously).

**First Attempt:**
My first attempt was to simply "test" the default error response with the following. This was meant to identify what spring was doing (which error it was using - I genuinly thought it would have been the `handleTypeMismatch` exception) - the method below is just one in the class (the one that I'm currently dealing with):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class IntegrationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(final BindException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request)
    {
        return super.handleBindException(ex, headers, status, request);
    }
}
```

I expected exactly the same error message as the default one, however this produced no response (or an empty response?).

**My "Solution":**
While i don't have to re-develop the wheel, i do have to do some hoop jumping:

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(final BindException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request)
    {               

        IntegrationResponse response = new IntegrationResponse(ex.getMessage());
        response.setErrors(ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors());

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, headers, status);
    }
```

Where errors is `private List<ObjectError> errors;` (`org.springframework.validation.ObjectError`)

So I'll have to try and replicate each overridable error in the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` (that applies to my situation) and treat it slightly differently, **you can see now why i just wanted to wrap the existing response**.

Just as a side note, I did try adding: `private Object error;` and `private BindingResult error;` as variables in my response object, however both attempts seem to reject my response object and show JUST the default message (as if there is no controller advice) with no hint as to why.

If anyone does discover how to skip the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` step and just wrap the default exception response object, I'll happily accept that answer.